# $f(x) = \tan x \sec x$, where $0^\circ \leq x \leq 360^\circ$. Find values of $x$, for which $f$ is an increasing function

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

I got till $(\sec x )(2\sec^2 x - 1) > 0$, but am not sure, how to proceed from here because I don't think I can simply divide out the $\sec x$ without changing the inequality.

I thought of splitting into two cases $\sec x > 0$ or $\sec x < 0$, but the answers I am getting are out of domain.

Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: How do you get $\sec x(2\sec^2x-1)$ as the derivative?

Comment: @egreg \begin{align*} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\tan(x)\sec(x)) &= (\sec^2(x))\sec(x)+\tan(x)(\sec(x)\tan(x)) \\ &= \sec(x)(\sec^2(x)+\tan(x)^2) \\ &= \sec(x)(2\sec^2(x)-1) \end{align*} as $\sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x) = 1$ by the Pythagorean identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u = \sec(x)$. Then, you're trying to solve $u(2u^2-1)\geq 0$, which has solutions $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\leq u\leq 0\text{ or } u\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ As either $\sec(x)\leq -1 < -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ or $\sec(x)\geq 1 > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, the above inequality will be satisfied exactly when $\sec(x)$ is positive: $$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)} > 0 \Leftrightarrow \cos(x) > 0$$ Therefore, all we have to do is consider where on the unit circle $\cos(x)$ is positive: $0^{\circ}\leq x < 90^{\circ}$ and $270^{\circ} < x\leq 360^{\circ}$.

Comment: Can I check how can you simply apply the condition $|\sec(x)| \geq 1$ when we know that $\sec (x)$ can adopt negative values, especially in the second and third quadrant?

Comment: Consider that $-1\leq \cos(x)\leq 1$, so $\sec(x)\leq -1$ or $\sec(x)\geq 1$. Therefore, $\sec(x)$ will never be in $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0\right]$, so we can just disregard that interval right off the bat. Also, $\sec(x)$ will be in $\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0\right)$ whenever $\sec(x)$ is positive, as $\sec(x)\geq 1$ when $\sec(x)$ is positive.

Comment: The main problem is that the derivative is not $\sec x(2\sec^2x-1)$.

Comment: Yes it is. \begin{align*} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\tan(x)\sec(x)) &= (\sec^2(x))\sec(x)+\tan(x)(\sec(x)\tan(x)) \\ &= \sec(x)(\sec^2(x)+\tan(x)^2) \\ &= \sec(x)(2\sec^2(x)-1) \end{align*} as $\sec^2(x)-\tan^2(x) = 1$ by the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: @MichaelLee Oh, well, if you want to take the hardest route… By the way, $2\sec^2x-1>0$ for every $x$ for which the secant is defined.

Comment: Right. That detail is sort of hidden in my answer (the fact that we disregard the interval $\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 0\right]$ and are left with $\sec(x) > 0$). Obviously, we could have recognized that $\sec^2(x)+\tan^2(x)\geq 0$ earlier.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{\sin{x}}{\cos^2x}\right)'=\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\cos^3x},$$ which gives $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$; $\left(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi\right]$.

If indeed, you want values of $x$ then $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$; $\frac{3\pi}{2}<x<2\pi$

Answer (score 1):

OK, now observe that $\sec^2x\ge1$, so $2\sec^2x-1>0$.

Hence the sign only depends on the first factor $\sec x$.